# counting total occurrence of values

Tags: sql

**i want to find the number of employees at the time when store is open**

```
select COUNT(e.employeeID) as PunchCount
from StoreMonitoring as s
inner join
EmployeeInAndOut as e on e.storeMonitoringID=s.storeMonitoringID 
where s.businessstarttime= (e.punchTime) and s.storeMonitoringID='12we'
group by e.employeeID
```

i want like this

```
Total Emp At Open 
----------------- 
3
```

**How can I achieve this?**

Comment: Just get there early. Or see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: right thankyou @Strawberry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want the count of employee  you shoudl remove the  e.employeeID from group by and eventually add the s.storeMonitoringID

```
select s.storeMonitoringID, COUNT(e.employeeID) as PunchCount
from StoreMonitoring as s
inner join 
EmployeeInAndOut as e on e.storeMonitoringID=s.storeMonitoringID 
where s.businessstarttime= (e.punchTime) and s.storeMonitoringID='12we'
group by s.storeMonitoringID
```